# Date Format getting disturb when creating .CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

I am creating a web scraper and then store the data in the .CSV file. 
My program is running fine but, there is a problem that the website from where I am retrieving data have a date which is in `(Month Day, Year)` format. So when I save the data in .CSV file it will consider the Year as another column due to which all the data gets manipulated. I actually want to store that data into `(MM-MON-YYYY)` and store Validity date in one column. I am posting my code below. Kindly, help me out. Thanks!

P.S: I am sorry for not writing the format I want in the original post.

```
package com.mufapscraping;

//import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
//import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class ComMufapScraping {

    boolean writeCSVToConsole = true;
    boolean writeCSVToFile = true;
    //String destinationCSVFile = "C:\\convertedCSV.csv";
    boolean sortTheList = true;
    boolean writeToConsole;
    boolean writeToFile;
    public static Document doc = null;
    public static Elements tbodyElements = null;
    public static Elements elements = null;
    public static Elements tdElements = null;
    public static Elements trElement2 = null;
    public static String Dcomma = ", 2";
    public static ArrayList<Elements> sampleList = new ArrayList<Elements>();

    public static void createConnection() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.1.1.123");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        String tempUrl = "http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01";
        doc = Jsoup.connect(tempUrl).get();
    }

    public static void parsingHTML() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

            tbodyElements = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
            //Element table = doc.getElementById("dataTable");

            if (tbodyElements.isEmpty()) {
                throw new Exception("Table is not found");
            }
            elements = tbodyElements.get(0).getElementsByTag("tr");

            for (Element trElement : elements) {
                trElement2 = trElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
                tdElements = trElement.getElementsByTag("td");
                FileWriter sb = new FileWriter("C:\\convertedCSV2.csv", true);
                for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        sb.append("  \n  ");
                    }
                    for (Iterator<Element> it2 = trElement2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Element tdElement = it.next();
                        sb.append(tdElement.text());
                        if (it2.hasNext()) {
                            sb.append("   ,   ");
                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    sb.flush();
                    sb.close();
                }

                System.out.println(sampleList.add(tdElements));
                /* for (Elements elements2 : zakazky) {
                System.out.println(elements2);
            }*/

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        createConnection();
        parsingHTML();

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: data has "Apr 18, 2016". Either you replace that ',' with something else or quote the whole string

Comment: actually that ',' is splitting the data into columns. So, if I replace it with something data will not split into columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appeding directly the element text in the `FileWriter`, format it first then append it.

So, replace the following line:

```
sb.append(tdElement.text());
```

into

```
sb.append(formatData(tdElement.text()));
```

---

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_MMM_d_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.US);
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_dd_MMM_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY", Locale.US);

public static String formatData(String text) {
    String tmp = null;

    try {
        Date d = FORMATTER_MMM_d_yyyy.parse(text);
        tmp = FORMATTER_dd_MMM_yyyy.format(d);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        tmp = text;
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

#### SAMPLE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] fields = new String[] { //
            "ABL Cash Fund", //
            "AA(f)", //
            "Apr 18, 2016", //
            "10.4729" //
    };

    for (String field : fields) {
        System.out.format("%s\n%s\n\n", field, formatData(field));
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
ABL Cash Fund
ABL Cash Fund

AA(f)
AA(f)

Apr 18, 2016
18-Apr-2016

10.4729
10.4729
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer. I've got what I exactly want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the method getElementsByTag many times you can use cssSelector which can be much easier and enables you to get the same output in few lines of code

```
public static void main (String []args) throws IOException{
    String tempUrl = "http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(tempUrl).get();

    Elements trElements = doc.select("#dataTable tbody tr");
    FileWriter sb = new FileWriter("C:\\convertedCSV2.csv", true);
    for(Element tr : trElements){
        Elements tdElements = tr.select("td");
        for (Element td : tdElements){
        sb.append(td.text());
        sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by simply surrounding your data with double quotes, so `month day, year` would become `"month day, year"`. Here's modified code that does the job for you:

```
package com.mufapscraping;

//import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
//import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class ComMufapScraping {

    boolean writeCSVToConsole = true;
    boolean writeCSVToFile = true;
    //String destinationCSVFile = "C:\\convertedCSV.csv";
    boolean sortTheList = true;
    boolean writeToConsole;
    boolean writeToFile;
    public static Document doc = null;
    public static Elements tbodyElements = null;
    public static Elements elements = null;
    public static Elements tdElements = null;
    public static Elements trElement2 = null;
    public static String Dcomma = ", 2";
    public static ArrayList<Elements> sampleList = new ArrayList<Elements>();

    public static void createConnection() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.1.1.123");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        String tempUrl = "http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01";
        doc = Jsoup.connect(tempUrl).get();
    }

    public static void parsingHTML() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

            tbodyElements = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
            //Element table = doc.getElementById("dataTable");

            if (tbodyElements.isEmpty()) {
                throw new Exception("Table is not found");
            }
            elements = tbodyElements.get(0).getElementsByTag("tr");

            for (Element trElement : elements) {
                trElement2 = trElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
                tdElements = trElement.getElementsByTag("td");
                FileWriter sb = new FileWriter("C:\\convertedCSV2.csv", true);
                for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        sb.append("  \n  ");
                    }
                    for (Iterator<Element> it2 = trElement2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Element tdElement = it.next();
                        sb.append('\"'); // surround your data
                        sb.append(tdElement.text());
                        sb.append('\"'); // with double quotes
                        if (it2.hasNext()) {

                            sb.append("   ,   ");
                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    sb.flush();
                    sb.close();
                }

                System.out.println(sampleList.add(tdElements));
                /* for (Elements elements2 : zakazky) {
                System.out.println(elements2);
            }*/

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        createConnection();
        parsingHTML();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you do want to split it. ok, then modify the first line by adding "year," column:

```
Element tdElement = it.next();
final String content = tdElement.text()
sb.append(content);
if (it2.hasNext()) {
    sb.append("   ,   ");
if (content.equals("Validity Date"))
    sb.append("Validity Year,");
```

you probably want to break after the for? or you'll overwrite the file elements.size()-1 times...

```
FileWriter sb = new FileWriter("C:\\convertedCSV2.csv", true);
for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) { ... }
break;
```