# How can I replicate this issue on my personal pc?

Tags: java, csv, proxy

I tried to copy this code onto my machine (from this post:[Date Format getting disturb when creating .CSV file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691942/date-format-getting-disturb-when-creating-csv-file-in-java#36691942))

```
package com.mufapscraping;

 //import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
//import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ComMufapScraping {

boolean writeCSVToConsole = true;
boolean writeCSVToFile = true;
//String destinationCSVFile = "C:\\convertedCSV.csv";
boolean sortTheList = true;
boolean writeToConsole;
boolean writeToFile;
public static Document doc = null;
public static Elements tbodyElements = null;
public static Elements elements = null;
public static Elements tdElements = null;
public static Elements trElement2 = null;
public static String Dcomma = ", 2";
public static ArrayList<Elements> sampleList = new ArrayList<Elements>();

public static void createConnection() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.1.1.123");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    String tempUrl = "http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01";
    doc = Jsoup.connect(tempUrl).get();
}

public static void parsingHTML() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

        tbodyElements = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
        //Element table = doc.getElementById("dataTable");

        if (tbodyElements.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("Table is not found");
        }
        elements = tbodyElements.get(0).getElementsByTag("tr");

        for (Element trElement : elements) {
            trElement2 = trElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
            tdElements = trElement.getElementsByTag("td");
            FileWriter sb = new FileWriter("C:\\convertedCSV2.csv", true);
            for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    sb.append("  \n  ");
                }
                for (Iterator<Element> it2 = trElement2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    Element tdElement = it.next();
                    sb.append(tdElement.text());
                    if (it2.hasNext()) {
                        sb.append("   ,   ");
                    }

                }

                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                sb.flush();
                sb.close();
            }

            System.out.println(sampleList.add(tdElements));
            /* for (Elements elements2 : zakazky) {
            System.out.println(elements2);
        }*/

        }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get the code to run in Eclipse. I get an exception error which looks like this when I tried to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1004)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:952)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
at exportDataFromWebsite.createConnection(exportDataFromWebsite.java:34)
at exportDataFromWebsite.main(exportDataFromWebsite.java:83)
```

I have done the following:

- Downloaded and added the jsoup jar file to the project path
- Named my class and the csv file the same way as in the code

Im pretty sure the problem is in these lines: `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.1.1.123");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        String tempUrl = "http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01";
        doc = Jsoup.connect(tempUrl).get();`

but I have no idea how to change this so that it works on my own pc. How do I know what proxy my pc is on? Any help would be appreciated please!

Btw... I am not copying someones code for my own benefit, I am trying to replicate the problem on my own machine and come up with a useful solution - but im getting errors when I try to run it. Thanks

Also, one more question, when I uncomment `//String destinationCSVFile = "C:\\convertedCSV.csv";`I get an error saying 'invalid escape sequence'... why is that? I thought its a string so its allowed as its in double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

you probably are not behind a proxy? then remove the lines:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.1.1.123");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

otherwise, if are you behind a proxy, possibly with authentication, you can try:

```
private static void setGlobalProxy(String proxyHost, int proxyPort, String authUser, String authPassword) {
    if (proxyHost != null && !proxyHost.isEmpty())
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
    if (proxyPort > 0)
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", ""+proxyPort);

    if (authUser != null && authPassword != null) {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
            }
        });

        System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);
    }
}
```